# Repeat items in list for schedule

Tags: python-3.x, list

I’m trying to make a program that tells a shift worker what days he/she is on and what days he/she is off. For example, on 4, off 4.
Here’s my code:

```
schedule = ['monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday']

on = 4

off = 4

count = 0

while count < 3:
    
    for x in range(on):
        
        print('on: ', schedule[x])
        
    for y in range(on,len(schedule)):
        
        print('off: ', schedule[y])
        
    count = count + 1
```

This prints:
on:  monday
on:  tuesday
on:  wednesday
on:  thursday
off:  friday
off:  saturday
off:  sunday

X3

What I’m trying to get it to do is:

on:  monday
on:  tuesday
on:  wednesday
on:  thursday
off:  friday
off:  saturday
off:  sunday
off:  monday
on:  tuesday
on:  wednesday
on:  thursday
on:  friday

And so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply create a dictionary where you will map Key:Value pair as Days and status and then iterate through it.
for example

```py
schedule = {'monday':"on",'tuesday':"on",'wednesday':"on",'thursday':"on",'friday':"off",'saturday':"off",'sunday':"off"}
```

and then iterate through the Schedule `dict`

```py
for day, status in schedule.items():
    print(f"{day}:{status}")
```